# AutoMapper 10.0.0: How to invoke the use of the static extension method "Mapper.Map<>()"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper, static-methods

I use:

- ASP.NET CORE MVC 3
- **AutoMapper 10.0.0**.

How can I call a static method `Mapper.Map<>()`?

Prior to this, such a call worked in 8.1.1 versions...

Answer (score 3):

The static API [was removed](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) in 9.0 version, now you should use instance api.

Comment: Does AutoMapper have an initialization api? Do not tell me how?

Comment: @Nikita automapper has [configuration](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) API which can be used to setup it.